# PDF Upload error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have developed an ASP.net C# function to upload PDF to the Database. when I try it in LocalHost, its working perfectly fine. but when I publish it in a server on IIS. it gives me the below error when I click upload:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
path + <path of the file>
```

```
string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
br.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Is there anything I should change in order to be able to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access it from localhost, both client and server are same so it can find file. but when you publish both the machine are isolated. basically you are not getting content from uploaded file, what you did is get the filename and fetch data from local hard disk, you should use following snippet.

```
int fileLen = fu.PostedFile.ContentLength;
Byte[] Input = new Byte[fileLen];
Stream myStream = fu.PostedFile.InputStream;
myStream.Read(Input, 0, Input.Length);
```

I have declared an byte array with size of bytes in uploaded file. and read byte from PostedFile InputStream.